# How does the Quora mobile website style Android UI elements?

Tags: android, google-chrome, user-interface

[image]

The top  status /  URL bar of Chrome, and Android's system status bar(!) are themed red by Quora!

Chrome looks like this:

[image]

How can a website ask Chrome and Android to change their appearance on a whim?

Comment: Web applications inside a browser are very different that native applications that are making use of Android's theming capabilities.

Comment: @DougStevenson Yes...? Clearly, Chrome can style Android system. I want to know how a random page can ask Chrome to style itself and Android.

Comment: OK, that wasn't clear at all.  All those giant screens with other text made it hard to digest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome especially introduced a new feature with Version 39 that allows the chrome header elements to be colorized with a meta tag. This following code would create an red android chrome address bar.

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#F00">
```

Edit: To support different devices it seems like you need to add additional meta tags

```
<!-- Windows Phone -->
<meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#F00">
<!-- iOS Safari -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="#F00">
```

Comment: Well the desktop version of chrome has custom themes in the chrome store. I think that is one reason they do not want the chrome ui to be changed from one page to another.